# How can I refer to the current puppet module's files directory?

Tags: puppet

This is most likely an anti-pattern, but I'd like to know nonetheless:

I need to extract a tgz which is in puppet and then move the contents somewhere else.  Is it possible, in a puppet `exec { }`, to refer to the file where it is stored on disk?

For example, puppet is available at `/usr/local/puppet`, and the tgz file I need it in `/usr/local/puppet/modules/components/files/file.tgz`.  In the `exec { }` can I do something like `command => "/bin/cp $modules/components/files/file.tgz /somewhere_else"` ?  Or do I have to declare a `file { source => "..." }` block first?

Comment: If you don't care for the capability of syncing file data from modules using `file { }`, could you not distribute the tarball independently from the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are correct if you run puppet with `puppet apply`.
In master-agent architecture using `exec` to copy file probably will not work at all.
In my opinion using `file` resource is more "puppet-like" but is has one significant drawback.

You can use:

```
file { '/some_path/somewhere_else':
  source => '/usr/local/puppet/modules/components/files/file.tgz',
}
```

This will create file `/some_path/somewhere_else` with the same content as `/usr/local/puppet/modules/components/files/file.tgz` (it will make a copy of the original file).
But if `/some_path` doesn't not exist in the file system, the command will fail.

If you are working with `tgz` files you can also consider using some of the [archive](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/tags/tar) puppet modules e.g [gini](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/gini/archive).

**UPDATE:**
I can propose two approaches:

1. Use [puppet file server](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html) to serve files (or define [module path](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.6/reference/dirs_modulepath.html) for old puppet versions). Next just use it e.g:

   ```
   file { '/some_path/somewhere_else':
      source => "puppet:///modules/components/file.tgz',
   }
   ```
2. Define custom facter fact [1](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/fact_overview.html), [2](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.4/custom_facts.html) that points path in your filesystem containing required files. E.g:

   ```
   file { '/some_path/somewhere_else':
      source => "${::my_custom_fact}/some_path/file.tgz',
   }
   ```

I do not think that any of the [core facts](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/core_facts.html) might be useful for you.

Comment: I suppose my question is more precisely: which variable/fact would I use to refer to the modules directory if I chose to skip the file { } block?  At the moment I have it hardcoded to the location where I know puppet to be.